# Merging phpunit codecoverage (coverage-html) results

Tags: php, code-coverage

Im running tests separatedly:

```
phpunit --log-junit result.xml Class1Test.php --coverage-php coverage.php --coverage-html, /codecoverage/ --whitelist Class1.php
phpunit --log-junit result.xml Class2Test.php --coverage-php coverage.php --coverage-html, /codecoverage/ --whitelist Class2.php
phpunit --log-junit result.xml Class3Test.php --coverage-php coverage.php --coverage-html, /codecoverage/ --whitelist Class3.php
```

the problem is, the coverage (both .html and .php) always overwrites the last. Any chance to merge/append to the last instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, PHPUnit doesn't allow it as you can see in the reports class creating the coverage files. For example : https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/master/src/Report/Clover.php

And, AFAIK, PHPUnit doesn't provide a way to generate custom coverage reports to code it yourself.

I just opened a bug on phpunit bugtracker: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4041

Maintainers may be interested

**Edit:**
This is considered as "out of scope" by Sebastian Bergman so there seem to remain two options to achieve your goal:

- Run two phpunit runs and code something to merge the resulting coverages afterwards
- Use another testing framework (Codeception for example)

Comment: yea, right, I had to do it on my own. As I remember, I could get an "array" as output, and I merged on my own